# Levi-Civita sign

Tags: matrices, tensor-products, kronecker-delta

Can any one explain to me why 
$$\sum_{k=1}^3 \varepsilon_{ijk}\varepsilon_{kij}=1$$
(Summing on $k$ from 1 to 3) 
Im trying to understand the index notation but cant see it yet. Thanks.

Comment: It is not clear what you are asking. Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to format your question so it is more readable

Comment: See [Levi-Civita symbol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levi-Civita_symbol).

Comment: First, $\sum\limits_{k=1}^3 \epsilon_{ijk} \epsilon_{kij} = 1 - \delta_{ij}$, not what are claiming. Second, $\epsilon_{ijk}$ is totally antisymmetric, it flips sign whenever you exchange two indices ( e.g. $\epsilon_{ijk} = -\epsilon_{jik}$).
A consequence of this is it is cyclic symmetric ($\epsilon_{ijk} = \epsilon_{jki} = \epsilon_{kij}$) and $\ne 0$ only when $i,j,k$ is a permutation of $1,2,3$.
When $i = j$, all the terms in the sum $\sum_{k=1}^3 \epsilon_{ijk}\epsilon_{kij}$ is zero. When $i \ne j$, there is only one term which is non-zero ( $k = 6 - i - j$ ) and has value $1$.